# ¿Como relacionar los productos de alguna tienda con códigos de barras?

Tags: código-de-barras

Con un lector de barras el código se muestra en pantalla, pero como indico a este código que descripción del producto debe tener? 
He visto que debo registrar en un Excel o una base de datos la descripción del producto con su respectivo código de barras. Pero es así como se hace? Porque que, que pasaría si compro al proveedor unas 100  unidades mas de ese producto. Tengo que registrar todos esos códigos de barra nuevos para indicarles a que se refieren ese producto. Es así como lo hacen los supermercados registran uno por unos sus productos. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para trabajar con códigos de barras tienes que tener almacenado en tu Base de Datos un código de producto muy aparte de tu Primary Key y tus demás atributos que necesites, ejemplo:

```
+---------+----------+------------------------+
| id_producto        | codigo_producto        |
+---------+----------+------------------------+
|       1            |        fsd234f         |
+---------+----------+------------------------+
```

Donde compruebas que ese código de producto existe en tu Base de Datos para posteriormente meter la cantidad de productos, para eso tienes que hacer un input para pedir esa cantidad de productos y registrarlos haciendo un insert en tu Base de Datos.

Así es como yo lo trabajo, espero que te sirva esta explicación.

Answer (score 0):

Cada producto tiene un SKU único en tu base de datos (vale decir, el código). Tomándome del ejemplo de [Javier Fr](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/23697/javier-fr), tu tabla **producto** tiene la forma

```
------------------------------------------
|  id  |   SKU    |  descripción          |
------------------------------------------
|   1  | asdfghj  | coca cola lata 300ml  |
|   2  | qwertyi  | chocolate nestlé 100g |
-------------------------------------------
```

En cambio, tu tabla **inventario** tiene la forma

```
 --------------------------------------
|  id_producto  | stock    | unidad   |
---------------------------------------
|       1       |  30      | unitaria |
|       2       |  50      | unitaria |
---------------------------------------
```

Cuando compras 100 botellas de coca cola 100 litros, **modificas la tabla inventario**.

No tienes que tocar la tabla **producto** a menos que te toque añadir **un SKU nuevo**, que no tenías previamente en tu maestro de códigos.

Por ejemplo compras a tus proveedores:

- 20 unidades de desodorante Old Spice
- 10 latas de coca cola.

La coca cola ya la tenías, así que sólo tienes que incorporar a tu tabla de productos el SKU del desodorante.

```
------------------------------------------
|  id  |   SKU    |  descripción          |
------------------------------------------
|   1  | asdfghj  | coca cola lata 300ml  |
|   2  | qwertyi  | chocolate nestlé 100g |
|   3  | zxcvbnm  | desodorante old spice |
-------------------------------------------
```

Y tu tabla de inventario debe reflejar el cambio

```
 --------------------------------------
|  id_producto  | stock    | unidad   |
---------------------------------------
|       1       |  40      | unitaria | <--- aumentó en 10
|       2       |  50      | unitaria |
|       3       |  20      | unitaria | <--- acabas de comprar 20
---------------------------------------
```

**Aclaraciones:**

1. La llave primaria de tu tabla de productos es el **id**. El campo SKU debe ser una **llave única**, pero **no es la llave primaria**, puesto que el día de mañana puedes decidir cambiar los códigos de SKU (digamos, quieres ponerlo en mayúsculas y añadir un sufijo de tres letras que identifica al proveedor. Con esta estructura puedes hacerlo sin tocar ninguna otra tabla.
2. La tabla de inventario tiene un campo `unidad` porque puedes tener productos que no se venden en forma unitaria, sino a granel. Por ejemplo, si el producto 4 fuese **pan**, y el pan **no se vende por unidad sino por kilo**

entonces en tu tabla de inventarios pondrías:

```
 --------------------------------------
|  id_producto  | stock    | unidad   |
---------------------------------------
|       1       |  40      | unitaria |
|       2       |  50      | unitaria |
|       3       |  20      | unitaria |
|       4       |  60      |     kg   | <--- pan
---------------------------------------
```

3. El campo unidad podría ir en la tabla de producto, pero me parece menos intuitivo ese enfoque a la hora de revisar la tabla de inventarios. Da un poco lo mismo.
4. En este ejemplo, la tabla de **inventario** tiene como llave primaria `id_producto`, que viene siendo el `id` del producto que referencia. Esto es decisión tuya, podría tener su propio `id` autoincremental siempre y cuando el `id_producto` sea una **llave única**. Lo que sí debe cumplirse es que haya una **llave foránea** en `id_producto` que obligue a la tabla **inventario** a sincronizarse con el `id` de la tabla **producto**, por ejemplo, si eliminas un producto descontinuado, que se elimine de la tabla inventario. O si cambias el ID de un producto (por alguna razón misteriosa) la tabla inventario se modificará también.
5. Considerando la unidad relacionada a cada producto, el código de barras generado debiera incorporar la cantidad de unidades. Por ejemplo, volviendo al pan

en tu tabla de productos tendrías:

```
------------------------------------------
|  id  |   SKU    |  descripción          |
------------------------------------------
|   1  | asdfghj  | coca cola lata 300ml  |
|   2  | qwertyi  | chocolate nestlé 100g |
|   3  | zxcvbnm  | desodorante old spice |
|   4  | qazwsxe  | pan, 1Kg              |
-------------------------------------------
```

Tu código de barras, cuando la gente pesa el pan, debiera traducirse a `SKU - unidades`. O sea:

- 5.5 kilos de pan se traducen a `qazwsxe-5.5`
- una lata de coca cola, se traduce a `asdfghj-1`.
- six-pack latas de coca cola se traducen a `asdfghj-6`. (a menos que comprar el six pack salga más barato, **en cuyo caso el six-pack debe tener otro SKU**)

El precio a cobrar relacionado con el código de barras es el precio unitario del SKU multiplicado por las unidades.

6. Evidentemente tienes que mantener una tabla de precios que indiquen el precio unitario de 1Kg de pan o  una lata de coca cola. Si de pronto sacas una oferta: "**sólo por hoy, lleve tres chocolates al precio de dos**" no cambias el precio unitario del chocolate.

Lo que haces es crear un nuevo sku:

```
------------------------------------------
|  id  |   SKU    |  descripción          |
------------------------------------------
|   1  | asdfghj  | coca cola lata 300ml  |
|   2  | qwertyi  | chocolate nestlé 100g |
|   3  | zxcvbnm  | desodorante old spice |
|   4  | qazwsxe  | pan, 1Kg              |
|   5  | plmokns  | pack 3 chocolates     |
-------------------------------------------
```

Cuando se acaba la promoción, eliminas ese SKU porque era algo temporal. Si hay 5 packs de 3 chocolates que no se vendieron, entonces hay que reincorporar los 15 chocolates al inventario del chocolate unitario.